# Get service account which used ressources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I have multiple groups of people accessing the same project in google cloud platform. I'm interested by the bigquery billing. I have multiple datasets, and whenever someone does something that is billed, I want to know which service account did it.

I found that I could add labels to datasets/table, and get this information in the billing export. However I really need to know which service account did it, because i might have multiple groups using the same dataset.

Comment: BigQuery exports to Stackdriver automatically which includes `authenticationInfo`. There is also BiqQuery Audit Logs.

Answer (score 0):

You may try viewing it on your Stackdriver Logging.

GCP Console > Logging > Resources: BigQuery / BigQuery Dataset / BigQuery Project. You may as well filter it with text "serviceaccount". More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

Query cost by identity is provided with an example here in the documentation. Refer the section "Example: Query cost breakdown by identity"

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/